# how do i use php explode method for indexes that can be output to html?

Tags: php

Need help understanding how to use php explode method. Apologies if this question is vague. i want to search for student from his/her id and return their info in html textboxes. From what i have read I need to explode the array produced into separate variables and then call the variables in my html. Can someone explain this method? PHP manual didn't help me.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "studentInfo_db";
$user = "George Jetson";
$password = "stopthisthing";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname; host=$host", $user, $password);

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include ('database_error.php');
    exit();
}

//get student id from text box
if(!isset($studentID)) {
$studentID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'studentID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if($studentID == NULL || $studentID == FALSE) {
        $studentID = 1;
    }
}
//prepare query 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM student
          WHERE studentID = :studentID';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':studentID', $studentID);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  //how do i get the individual values from query into textboxes?



echo $result['studentID']; //is this correct??
echo $result['name'];
echo $result['email'];
echo $result['GPA'];
```

?>

Comment: Use `var_dump($result)` the output will show you what keys to use

Comment: See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec2ff54eea7fc1e2a5f43d7908c4d9279edaad00 when you execute the code you will see `["xxxx"]` this is the key of the array. So for example `$array["foo"]` has the value "bar"

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No errors and the value of var_dump are what I want.  array(4) { ["studentID"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(8) "PO BLACK" ["email"]=> string(17) "poblack@gmail.com" ["GPA"]=> string(4) "3.51" } 1PO BLACKpoblack@gmail.com3.51........Now i need to learn how to output these values into html text boxes.

Comment: @allendks45 Just `echo` them in the respective textboxes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give it a try

```
 <input type="text" name="fname" value='<?php echo $result["studentID"]; ?> '>
```

And so on.

EDIT:  oops, didn't close the php tag. Sorry.